# Create binary tensor from vector in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I start with a 1D numpy array `x` (or tensorflow tensor) with `N` integer entries. Every entry is smaller or equal to `N`.
I now want to create a tensor `Y` of shape `(N,N)` (i.e. an NxN matrix) where `Y[i,j]=0` if `x[i]!=x[j]` and `Y[i,j]=1` if `x[i]==x[j]`.

Example with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2,1,2,3,4,2])
Y=np.zeros((x.shape[0],x.shape[0]))
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[0]):
        if x[i]==x[j]:
            Y[i,j]=1
```

**Output**

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

How do I create the same function efficiently in pure tensorflow code?

And: What if I have an extra batch dimension, so that the input `x` has shape `(B,N)` and I expect as an ouput `Y` with shape `(B,N,N)`. The batches are all independent of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape `x` to two different shapes, `(B, 1, N)` and `(B, N, 1)` so they can be properly broadcasted, then compare these two tensors, the result would be what you need with `1` being `True` and `0` being `False`:

```
import tensorflow as tf    
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2,1,2,3,4,2])

t = tf.constant(x)

r = tf.cast(
  tf.equal(
    tf.reshape(t, (-1, 1, t.shape[-1].value)), 
    tf.reshape(t, (-1, t.shape[-1].value, 1))
  ), tf.int8)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(r)
#array([[[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
#        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]]], dtype=int8)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([1,2,1,2,3,4,2])
x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = tf.tile(x, [x.shape[1], 1])
x_ = tf.transpose(x)
Y = tf.where(tf.equal(x,x_), tf.ones_like(x), tf.zeros_like(x))
```

There you have your vector x. You expand dims to have a matrix [1, x.shape]. Then you repeat it to have a copy of the same vector along the lines. x[i] == x[j] is therefore equivalent to x == x_ where x_ is the transposed of your matrix x.

`tf.where` is a conditional tensor. You give the condition (x == x_), and for each element, if it is true, it will take the first value (`tf.ones_like`) and if it is false it will take the second value (`tf.zeros_like`). Those `*_like(x)` functions are generating a tensor full of 0 or 1 with the same shape than x.